# Its possible to delete lookup column in corrupted sharepoint list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I have created 4 list in Listdefinition. But that list is corrupted.So the list is not opening.I want to delete that list.List contains Lookup columns So i was unable to delete.Is ther any way to delete the list ? please some one help for this,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have access to the server then download SharePoint Manager. Also try using SPD and if that fails PowerShell

Comment: can you access those lookup columns?

Comment: Could you please check the log and the data related with this correlation id?

Comment: Hai amal if i open the list in sharepoint manager is not opening above i added the image.

Comment: cannot access the lookup columns.. i tried powershell also but list cannot be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Use this Powershell script to delete the corrupted list.

Before your are Running this script check wheather RecycleBin is Empty.

stsadm.exe -o forcedeletelist -url http://Siteurl/Lists/listname/